# How to use one of my main PC monitors as remote monitor for my laptop -- KVM-like?

Tags: multiple-monitors, vnc, kvm-switch, remote-control

I have a desktop PC with 3 monitors and a laptop, which however doesn't really fit on my desktop, besides having a small screen and a fiddly keyboard. Both run Windows 10 Professional.

Is there a way to see my laptop's screen on one of my PC's monitors (or in a window on one of my PC's monitors) -- while controlling the laptop with my PC's mouse and keyboard?

I don't have administrative rights on the laptop, however I do so on the PC.

Answer (score 0):

OK I found out that what I want is simply a ([reverse](https://archive.realvnc.com/products/vnc/documentation/4.6/docs/af1050529.html)) VNC connection. This works with most flavors of VNC like for example with UltraVNC or TurboVNC.